# Number of Open Files - soft nofile vs ULIMIT

Tags: linux, ulimit

vendor software configuration requires these settings on our Linux server:

```
xerox soft nofile 16384
xerox hard nofile 262144
```

in file

```
/etc/security/limits.conf
```

Because of security consideration is it possible to replace these configuration in the user bash_profile?

can I use

```
ulimit -n 262144
```

in

```
/home/xerox/.bash_profile
```

Will it be the same?

**UPDATE**
Still confused and would like to know
What will be the equivalent commands to

xerox soft nofile 16384 and
xerox hard nofile 262144

in bash_profile

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To change the soft limit you need `ulimit -Sn`. With `-n` alone you set both limit which is more restricted. Use `ulimit -Hn` for decreasing the hard limit.

However increasing the hard limit is a root privilege. Then hard limit in your bashrc should be inferior to the one from `limits.conf`.

Note : hard limits are better set in `limits.conf`. A `chsh` could be handy to change the shell and use one which doesn’t read `.bashrc`. (Or editing simply the `.bashrc`).

Comment: Thank you! so what will be the equivalent commands to     ----  xerox soft nofile 16384             and     -------    xerox hard nofile 262144     in bash_profile?

Answer (score 1):

Actually no, If you set in .**bash_profile** whenever the user xerox get logins the .bash_profile will be executed and ulimit will get apply. Suppose if the Server gets reboot then ulimit will not be set automatically until unless xerox user gets login.
Setting in **/etc/security/limits.conf** will be permanent.